# About a way of filtering the access to web pages based on IP address

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am managing a server providing web administration pages and communicating with client apps.
I designed the web part which allows the public access through the 80 port.
However, I was told from my client that they want the server to allow only the access from their intra-net other than outside the company.
I thought it can be done if Tomcat has an ability to filter the access to web pages based on IP address.
However, I ended up in failing to find out a proper solution for that. I know Tomcat has already provided the filtering function according to a web project.
I came up with a way of getting around this problem and used it as follows:
I make two service tags in server.xml like

```
<Service name="Catalina"> 
<Connector port="80" ...>

<Service name="Catalina2"> 
<Connector port="8080" ...>
```

And make another clone for the additional service. Then, I block all the external accesses through 8080 port by the firewall set-up. This lives up to my client’s needs.
However, this is not a common way, I guess. Even, sometimes, the setting allows the external accesses which shouldn’t happen. On top of this, it’s not an efficient way from the maintaining point of view.

Anyhow, I don’t like it. It would be appreciated if someone told me the way.
Thanks for reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

A first step to IP filtering would be to configure your firewall / router.

You can also implement easy IP filtering in Servlet containers by creating a [javax.servlet.Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

You can map the filter using wildcards (`*`) to have all requests go through it and in the filter you can check the client's IP and block / deny serving the request based on your own rules.

Tomcat also comes with some built-in Filters. You might wanna take a look at them:

[Apache Tomcat 8 Container Provided Filters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html)

The built-in filters include [Remote Address Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter), [Remote Host Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Host_Filter) and [Remote IP Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter) (for proxies). These are mostly configurable with regular expressions and may be enough for your needs.